# Object passed to child became undefined after changing value on Context

Tags: react-native, react-context

I'm trying to update the value of `userInfo` in my `AuthContext.js` but when changing it, but when updating it the value of `userInfo` became undefined in my `HomeScreen`.

**AuthContext.js**

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState('');

    const update =  async (formData,) => {
        await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/user/update`, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            let resInfo = response.data;
            setUserInfo(resInfo);
            console.log(userInfo);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(resInfo));
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(`Profile Update Error ${e}`)
        });
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ update, userInfo }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
const Home = () => {
    const { update, userInfo } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const [username, setUsername] = useState(userInfo.users.username);

    useEffect(() => {
    }, [userInfo])

    return(
         <View style={{marginVertical: 5, flexDirection:'row'}}>
               <Text style={[styles.bodyText, {color: COLORS.primary,}]}>@</Text>
               <Text style={styles.bodyText}>{username}</Text>
         </View>
    )
}
export default Home;
```

So this is the code. The original code is longer so I just posted the part where the problem is at. The Axios API call is working and its updating the database side and the response is retrieving the updated user data. After updating I always get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`

I tried to browse the web for solutions but to no avail it doesn't. I hope professional here can help me with my problem since I'm fairly new on using React Native

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are incorrectly using the state value to get the username.

```
    const { update, userInfo } = useContext(AuthContext); //Get user

    const [username, setUsername] = useState(userInfo.users.username); //Set INITIAL value of username

//If you are not logged in, it will crash since your initial userInfo context value is an empty string (""). See explanation at the bottom
//If you are logged in, username will never get updated, so it will also crash since your initial context value is ("").
```

Your username will never get the updated userInfo object as it only executes on the first component mount.

You can simplify this by using a simple constant

```
const Home = () => {
    const { update, userInfo } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const username = userInfo?.users?.username //We use ? to prevent crashes if the userInfo object does not exist (If you are logged out)

//If the userInfo is updated, so will this const variable. No need for useState, as your userInfo is already a state. 

    return(
         <View style={{marginVertical: 5, flexDirection:'row'}}>
               <Text style={[styles.bodyText, {color: COLORS.primary,}]}>@</Text>
               <Text style={styles.bodyText}>{username || "No user found!!!"}</Text>
         </View>
    )
}
export default Home;
```

Also, I noticed some issues with your context. You set the initial value of userInfo to be an empty string, but it should be undefined (or null), because your userInfo is supposed to be an object, or something empty like undefined or null.

```
//const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(''); 
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(); //undefined or null
```

Another issue: You are setting the resInfo as a state, but you are using the stale userInfo to set your AsyncStorage item.

```
    setUserInfo(resInfo);
    console.log(userInfo); //Stale info, setUserInfo did not update userInfo yet
    AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(resInfo));
```

```
   setUserInfo(resInfo);
    console.log(resInfo); //New info
    AsyncStorage.setItem('resInfo', JSON.stringify(resInfo));
```

When you set the state in a function, it will get executed at the end of the call. That is why you always define a new variable like resInfo, and use resInfo as a "current" value. Otherwise it will always use the previous value.

Comment: I think I find the problem on my `AuthProvider`. When I console log this line `let resInfo = response.data` it gives me the updated user. But this `setUserInfo(resInfo)` doesn't work. I don't know why can't I set a new UserInfo.

Comment: Oh, I see another problem. I will update my post in a moment